# How to match up till '.' in string using perl

Tags: regex, perl, match

I am trying to write a match regex to extract text from a string in perl.

The string can be like something:

> I am a man. I am not a woman.

I want to match up to the first occurrence of '.', but if I use `[^.]`, it returns only the first character i.e. 'I' instead of 'I am a man'.

How do I write my `[]` expression?

Comment: `^.*?\.` starts from beginning and captures till `\.` or your desire '.'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^[^.]*
```

which means any number of character that is not a dot, at the beginning of the string

Comment: You don't need the first caret `^`. Regex matching starts at the beginning of the string anyway, so `[^.]*` will do fine.

Comment: Using the `^` makes it easier to read. It also a good habit since it prevents needless and even unwanted backtracking in more complicated patterns such as `[^.]*.`

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a quantifier (how many times you want your pattern to be matched). By default, it's one.

```
[^.]{5}
```

This matches anything that is not a `.` 5 times.

```
[^.]{2,}
```

This matches anything that is not a `.` 2 times or more.

```
[^.]{2,5}
```

This matches anything that is not a `.` 2, 3, 4 or 5 times.

```
[^.]*
```

The quantifier `*` means 0 times or more (it's a shortcut for `{0,}`). So this matches anything that is not `.` 0 times or more.

```
[^.]+
```

The quantifier `+` means once or more (it's a shortcut for `{1,}`). So this matches anything that is not `.` once or more. **This is what you want**.

```
[^.]?
```

The quantifier `?` means 0 times or once (it's a shortcut for `{0, 1}`). So this matches anything that is not `.` 0 times or once.